# css selectors first and last occurance

Tags: html, css

I want to set a style on the first and last of the elements. The number of sections can vary on each odd/even, so I can not do anything like "every 3rd element then use this CSS-rule". The elements are inside one parent element, here a `<div>`.

What I want to achieve is that everytime the odd-section occures for the first time in this list of `span`s, I want to add some style, and the samme with the last occurance of odd-section. Then It begins again with the same logic for the even-section, and again for the odd-section, and then again even-section:

```html
<div>
  <span class="odd-section"></span>
  <span class="odd-section"></span>
  <span class="odd-section"></span>
  <span class="even-section"></span>
  <span class="even-section"></span>
  <span class="even-section"></span>
  <span class="odd-section"></span>
  <span class="odd-section"></span>
  <span class="odd-section"></span>
  <span class="even-section"></span>
  <span class="even-section"></span>
  <span class="even-section"></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

It would be so much better if every odd-section / even-section part had a parent `<div>`, but that is not the case here.

Comment: `It would be so much better if every odd-section / even-section part had a parent <div/>` that's true and would make your html more structured. So why don't try to change this part ? Moreover all your `<span>` are not closed :/

Comment: Are solutions in javascript allowed? in javascript this would be easy, CSS I don't know

Comment: what kind of style you want to apply?

Comment: I genuinely wish it were not possible to shut down an asker's question when an answerer is in the middle of writing a response. All that happens is the answerer completes their response and then can't post it.

Comment: If you are not in a position to change the markup and surround each section with `<div>...</div>`, you could use a dab of javascript here.

The conventional approach is to:

 - loop through the `<spans>`
 - verify which conditions each `<span>` matches
 - add a `class` which describes those conditions
 - style those `classes` in your stylesheet

Comment: const div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    const spans = [... div.getElementsByTagName('span')];

    for (span of spans) {

      switch (true) {

      case (span === spans[0]) : span.classList.add('first'); break;
      case (span === spans[(spans.length - 1)]) : span.classList.add('last'); break;
      case (span.classList[0] !== span.previousElementSibling.classList[0]) : span.classList.add('first'); break;
      case (span.classList[0] !== span.nextElementSibling.classList[0]) : span.classList.add('last'); break;

      }
    }

Comment: div {
      width: 280px;
    }

    .first,
    .last {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .odd-section {
      color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
    }

    .even-section {
      color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }

Comment: <div>
      <span class="odd-section">One</span>
      <span class="odd-section">morning</span>
      <span class="odd-section">when</span>
      <span class="even-section">Gregor</span>
      <span class="even-section">Samsa</span>
      <span class="even-section">woke</span>
      <span class="odd-section">from</span>
      <span class="odd-section">troubled</span>
      <span class="odd-section">dreams,</span>
      <span class="even-section">he</span>
      <span class="even-section">found</span>
      <span class="even-section">himself</span>
    </div>

Comment: @caramba yes, please give me a suggestion!

Comment: @RMT pete already did, see the second code snippet he posted in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60280070/2008111

Comment: @RMT - Please also see the javascript solution I have written out in 4 comments above. The first comment (_"If you are not in a position to [...]"_) has the introduction to the solution, the next comment has the javascript, the next comment has the CSS and the next comment has the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following adjacent sibling selector and first child pseudo selector to select the first of each group

If the spans are always in groups of 3s, then you could use a double adjacent for the last of each group

```css
.odd-section:first-child,
.even-section+.odd-section {
  /* this highlights the first in each group */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.odd-section+.odd-section+.odd-section {
  /* this highlights the last in each group */
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, if your odds and evens are not in groups of three, you will not be able to use css to select the last element of the group, instead you would either need to add a class using your server side language, or use a js approach

Below is a quick example of how you can use jquery to add  a class to the last of each group

```js
$('.odd-section').filter(function() {
  return $(this).is(':last-child') || $(this).next('.even-section').length;
}).addClass('last-section');
```

```css
.odd-section:first-child,
.even-section+.odd-section {
  /* this highlights the first in each group */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.last-section {
  /* this highlights the last in each group */
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="even-section">even</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
  <span class="odd-section">odd</span>
</div>
```